# CTFontRef is not displayed on ios 7.1.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring, core-text, uifont

I use CoreText to load and display custom fonts in my application (the number of the fonts near 120).
There is table with a fonts list in the application.
In the table any row displayed with custom font.
I load the fonts so:

```
CFArrayRef descriptors = CTFontManagerCreateFontDescriptorsFromURL((CFURLRef)_fontURL);
        if (descriptors)
        {
            CTFontDescriptorRef fontDescriptor = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(descriptors, 0);
            CTFontRef createdFont = CTFontCreateWithFontDescriptor(fontDescriptor, 20.0, NULL);
            self.font = createdFont;
            if (createdFont)
            {
                CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL((CFURLRef)_fontURL, kCTFontManagerScopeProcess, &error);               
                CFRelease(createdFont);
            }
            CFRelease(descriptors);
        }
```

This code correct works on any iOS versions except 7.1.2. There is a strange problem in 7.1.2.
When I scroll the table, some fonts is not displayed or displayed with not correct characters. (Some times this problem appear after log time of the scrolling)
This problem present only on 7.1.2.

What I've tried:
    1. I've tried add all my fonts to UIAppFonts of the plist file, but it's not helped. But I've known what if I add more then 114 font, then the application will be crashed.
    2. I've checked a double registration of the font, but it also hasn't helped.
    3. I've checked that all fonts is loaded from main thread.

Nothing of what I've made has not help. What of the reason of this behaviour in iOS 7.1.2?
I'll be  glad to any version.

**UPDATE** 4.09.215

If I do  not check a double registration of the fonts I receive a following error (for different fonts):

```
Error Domain=com.apple.coretext Code=104 "The operation couldn’t be completed. 
(com.apple.coretext error 104 - Could not register the font file 'file:///private/var/mobile/Applications/694011F5-A0F3-4A54-87B4-138F4ED8E781/AppName.app/fontsForEditor/LANEPOSH.ttf')" 
UserInfo=0x1754d6b0 {CTFailedFontFileURL=file:///private/var/mobile/Applications/694011F5-A0F3-4A54-87B4-138F4ED8E781/AppName.app/fontsForEditor/LANEPOSH.ttf,
NSDescription=Could not register the font file 'file:///private/var/mobile/Applications/694011F5-A0F3-4A54-87B4-138F4ED8E781/AppName.app/fontsForEditor/LANEPOSH.ttf'}
```

And CTFontManagerCreateFontDescriptorsFromURL returns NULL.

If I check a double registration (for example if I open this page twice), I do not have error (because I do not call the registration), but CTFontManagerCreateFontDescriptorsFromURL returns NULL.
I think it happens when I **try** **create** CTFontDescriptiorRef for second time.

I set a font to a label by this way:

```
- (void)_updateLabelFont
{
    CFStringRef fontName = CTFontCopyPostScriptName(self.model.font);

    UIFont* font = [UIFont fontWithName:(__bridge NSString*)fontName size:FONT_SIZE];

    if (fontName)
    {
        CFRelease(fontName);
        fontName = NULL;
    }

    self.fontNameLabel.font = font;
}
```

Also I've tried to change UILabel to TTTAttributedLabel (to avoid a creating of a instance of UIFont), I've receive a same effect.
I've noticed that if I've removed double registration of the fonts, then problem appear more quickly (I recreate cells after user's touched one).

Comment: I notice you're calling `CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL` without capturing the error. This seems like a mistake - you're throwing away the possibility of useful information. I would start by capturing and logging the error just to see whether there is one!

Comment: Also, if the problem occurs only when scrolling a table, then one would think the place to look is not with the font registration but with how you are configuring the table cell. But you don't show that...